# Force CCNet project build from C# application or command line

Tags: c#, command-line, cruisecontrol.net

If there is a way to start a particular Cruise Control project build on a http:\a.b.com\ccnet server programmatically? From C# program or command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [CCCmd](https://github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET/blob/master/project/CCCmd/Help.txt) command line tool:

```
CruiseControl.Net Command-Line Utility
Provides command-line access to a CruiseControl.Net server

CCCmd <command> [options]

command: one of the following actions
  help:         display this help screen
  retrieve:     retrieve details on a project or server
  forcebuild:   forces a build on a project
  abortbuild:   aborts a build on a project
  startproject: starts a project integrator
  stopproject:  stops a project integrator
```

Comment: works! here the command line arguments:
cccmd ForceBuild --server:tcp://127.0.0.1/ccnet --project:MyProject